# Which British author wrote about Shellworlds before Iain M. Banks?

Tags: story-identification, iain-m-banks

Iain M. Banks is remembered as creator of Shellworlds-artificial planets with layers of habitable space within them.

Except this is incorrect. I distinctively remember reading a British author in my youth that had a whole SF series dedicated to this very idea. One of the titles was something along *Invasion from the Centre*.

Does anyone remember who the author might be?

Comment: Could you be thinking of the "Great Ship" novels by Robert Reed? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marrow_(novel)

Comment: Brian Stableford, "Journey to the Center" was the one I was looking for. I would like to thank everyone for helping me, and giving other interesting examples.

Comment: Not really relevant to the (in any case rather old) question, but the German Perry Rhodan series had a shell word with distinct layers in 1965 (Perry Rhodan Volume 206, "Schrecken der Hohlwelt" (Terrors of the Hollow Planet)). So Stableford is not the inventor of the concept, either.

Comment: May be of interest as a related topic https://publicdomainreview.org/essay/stories-of-a-hollow-earth

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Brian Stableford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Stableford), *Journey to the Center* (DAW Books, 1982), followed by *Invaders from the Centre* (1990) and *The Centre Cannot Hold* (1990).
The trilogy is also published as the *[Asgard Trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Stableford#Asgard)*, as *Asgard's Secret*, *Asgard's Conquerers* and *Asgard's Heart*.

> The galaxy is full of mysteries. Asgard one of the most inexplicable. Many different species & many types of individual sought answers to its enigmas. Anthropologists, fortune hunters, scientists, gangsters, politicians & explorers found reason to congregate on the planet which possibly wasn't a planet. To stand on the artificial surface & wonder how many subcutaneous levels the planet contained, & what, if anything, was at the center, to examine the artifacts on the reachable levels where the temperature approached absolute zero.

[image: front cover of Journey to the Center]

Comment: Also, in 1979, American author Ted Reynolds wrote the novella "Ker-Plop", nominated for a Hugo in 1980, that featured a 'ship' with a 5000 mile radius and layered civilizations.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the [Orbitsville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbitsville) series by Bob Shaw (from Northern Ireland, not technically Britain but still United Kingdom)?

The title in the series are *Orbitsville*, *Orbitsville Departure*, and *Orbitsville Judgement*.

You can find more information about fiction in which this kind of setting (usually called “Dyson spheres”) appears in the rich, if haphazardly organised, Wikipedia article about [*Dyson spheres in popular culture*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_spheres_in_popular_culture).

Comment: As I recall Orbitsville is just a (Dyson) sphere, not lots of concentric levels as the question describes.

Answer (score 1):

From wikipaedia:

> The Cageworld series is a science fiction series by Colin Kapp which takes place in a distant future where humanity lives on nested Dyson spheres. The four books are Search for the Sun (1982) (also published as Cageworld); The Lost Worlds of Cronus (1982); The Tyrant of Hades (1984) and Star Search (1984).